# How to build kernel 4.15.0 on ubuntu 18.04 and avoid missing libperf-jvmti.so

Tags: 18.04, kernel, compiling, docker

I'm trying to build kernel 4.15.0 to apply [patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202665) with Docker. But I encountered the problem that `libperf-jvmti.so` was not found on building the kernel.

Could anybody tell me how to fix this error?

```
root@513ceb15941f:/data/linux-4.15.0$ fakeroot debian/rules binary-

....

headers binary-generic binary-perarch
install -m755 /data/linux-4.15.0/debian/build/tools-perarch/tools/perf/perf /data/linux-4.15.0/debian/linux-tools-4.15.0-66/usr/lib/linux-tools-4.15.0-66
install -m755 /data/linux-4.15.0/debian/build/tools-perarch/tools/perf/libperf-jvmti.so /data/linux-4.15.0/debian/linux-tools-4.15.0-66/usr/lib/linux-tools-4.15.0-66
install: cannot stat '/data/linux-4.15.0/debian/build/tools-perarch/tools/perf/libperf-jvmti.so': No such file or directory
debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:668: recipe for target 'install-perarch' failed
make: *** [install-perarch] Error 1
```

## Docker Build File

Environments and code are here.

https://github.com/fx-kirin/docker-ubuntu-kernel-build

#### Relative Link

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1761379

Comment: There is no `libperf-jvmti.so` in anywhere in the directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally found out JDK installation was needed. After installing it, the compilation was finished successfully.

```sh
apt install default-jdk
```

Comment: And I fixed the github repo. So there is no error on building the kernel.